# linux avconv: how to extract a parameter sceme to create new video?

Tags: linux, video, libav, mp4box

I have different video files, clips. Some are mp4, m4v, flv... withdifferent rates orI don't know which differences more.

The point is, I want to merge files, which I created from input files with avconv (not ffmpeg!!!) and then join them wit MP4Box.
But due to different video parameters, I get an error:
"Can not add clipx.mp4 (bad parameter)"

I need same input scemes. How can I create clips with finally the same sceme?
Given the size,e.g. 1280x720 pix resolution is always same.
I do want all in a command line, in a script, with several different input files and finally create one unique output video.

Comment: What's the command you use to create a video with avconv ?

Comment: "avconv -r 25 -ss $((start)) -i "$film" -t $((seconds)) -an -c:v libx264 /home/user/clip$((nr)).mp4"


and after creating all clips, I use MP4Box to create a unique movie:
MP4Box $(printf -- "-cat %s " clip?.mp4) -new "/home/user/$videoname"


Explanation: I select sequences from input movies, create mini clips and want to join all those clips then to one single video file.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information:
I can choose one video file in -> avidemux and then add several more files with different scemes. All are in a sequence that I can save the complete new movie with one unique setting, like h264, mp4...

But I have only an avidemux gui (no command line interface) and the way to collect via avidemux gui is too much work and needs too much time.